# Buffer write in Mac will hang

Tags: c++, linux, macos

The following code will hang in my Mac; but pass with smaller data size. Any suggestion on that? I'm thinking it's related with OS configuration, because it works in other Mac with the same version.

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int pipes[2];

  int rc = ::pipe(pipes);
  if (rc < 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  string data =
    "This data is much larger than BUFFERED_READ_SIZE, which means it will "
    "trigger multiple buffered async reads as a result.........";

  while (data.length() < 3 * 16 * 4096) {
    data.append(data);
  }

  size_t offset = 0;

  while (offset < data.length()) {
    ssize_t length =
      ::write(pipes[1], data.data() + offset, data.length() - offset);

    if (length < 0) {
      // TODO(benh): Handle a non-blocking fd? (EAGAIN, EWOULDBLOCK)
      if (errno == EINTR) {
        continue;
      }
      return -1;
    }

    offset += length;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Mac Info:

```
Klauss-MacBook-Pro:linux klaus$ uname -a
Darwin Klauss-MacBook-Pro.local 15.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Klauss-MacBook-Pro:linux klaus$ otool -L ./w
./w:
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
Klauss-MacBook-Pro:linux klaus$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Is there something READING the pipe somewhere? I would have thought you needed to fork your code between the creation of the pipe and the write, with something reading the pipe executing in the other fork? Otherwise, the writer will block when the OS's buffer is full (a few kilobytes, most likely) until the pipe has been read - the OS doesn't really KNOW that there is nothing in your code or the rest of the system that reads the pipe.

Comment: Take a look at this doc http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-Atomicity.html , especially "...Also, once PIPE_BUF characters have been written, further writes will block until some characters are read". The doc is for GNU libc, but the same is applicable to any libc in a unix-like system, including MacOS X.